# Flask website for cancer prediction gives same output

Tags: python

I am working on a flask website which predict prostate cancer using KNN.I don't know why but even if I enter data of benign cell as the input ,it shows the cell is malignant .I even changed the machine learning code still it gives wrong output .

app.py

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rad = float(request.form['radius'])
        tex = float(request.form['texture'])
        par = float(request.form['perimeter'])
        area = float(request.form['area'])
        smooth = float(request.form['smoothness'])
        compact = float(request.form['compactness'])
        symme= float(request.form['symmetry'])
        frac = float(request.form['fractal_dimension'])

        mypred = np.array([[rad, tex, par, area, smooth, compact,symme, frac]])
        my_prediction = model.predict(mypred)

        return render_template('cancerresult.html', prediction=my_prediction)
```

cancerresult.html :

```
<body>

    {% block body %}
       {% if prediction==1 %}
      <h1> You have CANCER</h1>
      {% elif prediction== 0 %}
      <h1>No CANCER</h1>
      {% endif %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

This is the full code https://github.com/devika-harshan/prostatecancer

Answer (score 0):

1 - as first change pcancer.ipynb to pcancer.py to easy integrated with flask
2- check pcancer.py is working with no error with same behavior of pcancer.ipynb 
3- the last stage intgration between pcancer.py and flask in one file